# How do I use "stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream())"

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

How do I use stream.pipe?

I'm running a function that outputs:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const screenshot = require('screenshot-stream');
const stream = screenshot('http://google.com', '1024x768');
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('picture.png'));
```

My next step is taking that picture (picture.png) and assigning it here:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/img')
```

In other words, what is the path to the image so I can upload it?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, Your project directory name is "PROJECT", And you executed this file from the root directory of your project, Then the PICTURE.png file will be created in the root directory.

And the path to that file'll be `__dirname + "/PICTURE.png"` if you are still in the root directory of your project.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion is with "stream.pipe". I don't understand how it works--it's not putting the picture in the root directory.

Comment: I can't really tell you anything more without seeing the code

Comment: I updated the original post with more detailed code.  Please let me know if you have any ideas